# How to loop inside custom field group in WordPress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to emulate the following layout on WordPress pages.

[image]

but how do I make the encircled city dynamic? The layout is set that under a specific state, all stores on that state is listed below it.

On SQL, this may mean:

```
select city where address = "";
```

I just don't know how to translate my SQL knowledge into a WordPress dynamic page.

So far my WordPress page code is:

```
<section class="main-content">

    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'branches', 'orderby'=>'post_id', 'order'=>'ASC' ) ); ?>

    <div class="resource-row clearfix">

        <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
            $address = get_field('address');

        ?>
    </div><!-- resource-row -->
</section><!-- main-content -->
```

EDIT:

As of now, based on the above image, what I can do is display the following:

> Cupertino
>       1 Infinite Loop 
>       Cupertino, CA

However, I cannot seem to display the state (eg. California) for which the address is under, as well as the other address on the row.

How do I make it such that for each State, the corresponding address is displayed under it?

Comment: Vishnu, your question is not clear enough. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Ok, will update @MontyPython. Thanks

Comment: Updated. Thank you @MontyPython

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would have been of great help if you had shared the table structure. Assuming that there are three separate records for:

1. Cupertino
2. Infinite Loop
3. Cupertino, CA

We can do this:

```
select group_concat(x separator ' ') address
from (select 'Cupertino 1' x union
select 'Infinite Loop' union
select 'Cupertino, CA') t;
```

Comment: How do you do it on WordPress? I'm quite new in backend WordPress development and don't know how to translate regular SQL queries to WordPress queries